# How to get the second part from a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have string array where value is like this:

```
strMystring[0] = "George,Michael   -  1234";
```

I want to get the numeric value from the string using substring. I'm trying using following code but I get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

```
strGSPN[0].Substring(strGSPN[0].IndexOf('-') + 1, strGSPN[0].Length)
```

How do I get this value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String.Split`, followed by `String.Trim()` should do it easily.

Comment: Can u gimme the code for this

Comment: Here is tutorial for [String.Split](http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-split.htm) and this is what [String.Trim](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-trim-method/) does. This should give you a solid foundation in how to use these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `Substring` is expecting a start index and a length, not an end index:

```
public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);
```

The length should be the total length minus the index of the `-`.

However, would be simpler to use `Split`:

```
var result = strGSPN[0].Split('-')?[1]?.Trim();
```

Notice the use of the [Conditional array and indexer access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) after the split in case there was no delimiter in the string.

Comment: nice usage of conditional array operators!

Answer (score 1):

Others have posted similar answers.

You are looking for the substring that starts at "-" and goes to the end of the string. What you did is started at indexOf("-") + 1 and went past the end of the string.

```
    string x = "George - 1234";
    string b = x.Substring(x.IndexOf("-") + 1, (x.Length - (x.IndexOf("-") + 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the index of the final character in the string, which is Length - 1. You're using just **strGSPN[0].Length**, which will be out of bounds, because the length starts counting with 1, rather than 0, but indices start with 0, so when you get the character at string.Length, you're getting the place of the string at the place one after the final string, resulting in the exception. Try the following:

```
strGSPN[0].Substring(strGSPN[0].IndexOf('-')+1, strGSPN[0].Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, the second parameter is the length of the substring you want. You are exceeding the length of the string which causes your exception.

Instead of calculating the length yourself or splitting the string, you can simply use the overload of `Substring` that accepts the start index *only*. It will take the remaining portion of the string. After that you simply need to trim the result.

```
var result = strGSPN[0].Substring(strGSPN[0].IndexOf('-')+1).Trim();
```

[MSDN String.Substring(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_)